# Eliminating row gaps in excel

Tags: excel

I have an excel datasheet with a column of 30 cells (A1:A30) that fills up automatically and randomly, so that some of the cells contain data and some don't.
I need to create a new list in the next column (b1:b30) containing only the data and no duplicates, but once the cells are filled I can't touch the datasheet so I can't use sorting, and sadly I work in an environment where macros aren't enabled so no VBA.

So far this is what I've come up with:

```
B1=IF(A1=0,IF(A2=0,...,IF(A29=0,A30,A29),A28),A27),...A2),A1)
```

And then

```
B2=IF(A1=OR(0,B1),IF(A2=OR(0,B1),...
```

And so on until by B30 I get an expression so horrifying it literally have me a nightmare.

It's there an easier way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could always look at using PowerQuery or Pivot table if need be.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the new Dynamic Array formulas UNIQUE and FILTER:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A1:A30,A1:A30<>""))
```

Put that in B1 and Excel will spill down the list.

[image]

---

If one does not have access to those formula then put this in B1 and copy down:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($A$1:$A$30)/(ROW($A$1:$A$30)=MATCH($A$1:$A$30,A:A,0)),ROW(A1))),"")
```

[image]